# Changing alignment within a vertical layout group

Tags: unity, c#, gui

I have a vertical layout group that has text bubbles instantiated into it.
Instantiating them always aligns them to "lower middle".
However, I'd like to have them on opposite sides for a message app effect.

Right now, I'm changing the anchoredPositions of each instantiated UI object in Update. Is there any better way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a wrapper RectTransform around each bubble which takes up the full width, with a `HorizontalLayoutGroup` component. Set the Child Alignment on the left-side messages to Middle Left, and on the right-side messages to Middle Right. So your hierarchy looks like this

```
|-ChatMessages (VerticalLayoutGroup, Child Alignment = Lower Center)
|----LeftMessage (HorizontalLayoutGroup, Child Aligment = Middle Left)
|--------Message (Text, Image, Whatever)
|----RightMessage (HorizontalLayoutGroup, Child Aligment = Middle Right)
|--------Message (Text, Image, Whatever)
|----LeftMessage (HorizontalLayoutGroup, Child Aligment = Middle Left)
|--------Message (Text, Image, Whatever)
|----RightMessage (HorizontalLayoutGroup, Child Alignment = Middle Right)
|--------Message (Text, Image, Whatever)
```

Comment: I tried this and it didn't work out well. Made my own system instead.

Comment: Odd. It worked exactly as I expected when I tried it.

Comment: The thing is if I set the text bubbles to be 100% of the width of the Vertical Layout Group it doesn't look clean. I'm using a content size fitter on the left/right message, and a horizontal layout group. When I use both of these (vertical and horizontal), it doesn't work out well. Could you upload a gif of your setup?

Comment: I followed this;
http://hilllo.com/limit-max-width-of-a-layout-component-in-unity/
Very similar to your solution. It works.